# I am getting the Path has no attribute join error

Tags: python, pathlib

Here is the code:

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
PROJECT_DIR = Path.join(BASE_DIR, "online_auction")

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = "django-insecure-v$!(s!s!v7ny#fcq&1_y)c%i17^*&n)h0fl8)9ms#q-)$7&$fs"

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
```

and this is the error message:

```
PROJECT_DIR = Path.join(BASE_DIR, "online_auction")
AttributeError: type object 'Path' has no attribute 'join'
```

Please help. what should I do

Comment: use `os.path.join()` . See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-join-method/

Comment: do I have to import os or what?

Comment: You can just do `Path(BASE_DIR, "online_auction")` or `BASE_DIR / "online_auction"`

Answer (score 0):

The `BASE_DIR` is a `pathlib.Path` object. This objects provide an easy way to join them by just using the `/` operator

```py
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
PROJECT_DIR = BASE_DIR / "online_auction"
```